# Ratio between two groups

Tags: percentages, ratio

I want to know among what is the ratio of insured people with disease $x$ to uninsured people with disease $x$.  Here are my numbers.

- Insured, disease $x = 3600$
- Uninsured, disease $x = 950$
- Insured, no disease $x = 100$
- Uninsured, no disease $x = 150$

I’m struggling to understand if I should use $3600:950$ or if I should use $(3600/3700):(950/1100)$. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let:

- $d_I=3600$ be the number of people with the disease among the insured;
- $d_U=950$ be the number of people with the disease among the uninsured;
- $\overline{d_I}=100$ be the number of people without the disease among the insured;
- $\overline{d_U}=150$ be the number of people with the disease among the uninsured.

The ratio of insured people with disease $x$ to uninsured people with disease $x$ is:
$$
\frac{d_I}{d_U} = \frac{3600}{950}
$$
It is the odds of finding someone insured among the diseased.

Other odds that might be of interest are:

- The odds of finding someone insured among the non-diseased $\frac{\overline{d_I}}{\overline{d_U}}$;
- The odds of finding someone with the disease among the insured $\frac{d_I}{\overline{d_I}}$;
- The odds of finding someone with the disease among the uninsured $\frac{d_U}{\overline{d_U}}$.

And finally, we could also compute the odds ratio $OR$:

$$
OR 
= \frac{\frac{d_I}{d_U}}{\frac{\overline{d_I}}{\overline{d_U}}}
= \frac{\frac{d_I}{\overline{d_I}}}{\frac{d_U}{\overline{d_U}}}
= \frac{d_I \cdot \overline{d_U}}{\overline{d_I} \cdot d_U}
= \frac{3600 \times 150}{100 \times 950}
\approx 5.68
$$

Since $OR > 1$, it means that the odds of having the disease (vs not having the disease) among the people with insurance is larger than the odds of having (vs not having the disease) the disease among the people without insurance.

---

Your final expression is the relative risk $RR$, a concept similar to the $OR$ but related with risk (probability) instead of odds.

- The risk of finding someone with the disease among the insured $\frac{d_I}{d_I + \overline{d_I}}$;
- The risk of finding someone with the disease among the uninsured $\frac{d_U}{d_U + \overline{d_U}}$;
- The risk of finding someone insured among the diseased $\frac{d_I}{d_I + d_U}$;
- The risk of finding someone insured among the non-diseased $\frac{\overline{d_I}}{\overline{d_I} + \overline{d_U}}$.

The relative risk of having the disease among the insured vs having the disease among the uninsured is then:
$$
RR_d 
= \frac{\frac{d_I}{d_I + \overline{d_I}}}{\frac{d_U}{d_U + \overline{d_U}}}
= \frac{\frac{3600}{3700}}{\frac{950}{1100}}
\approx 1.13
$$

Note that this is different to the relative risk of being insured among the diseased vs being insured among the non-diseased :
$$
RR_I 
= \frac{\frac{d_I}{d_I + d_U}}{\frac{\overline{d_I}}{\overline{d_I} + \overline{d_U}}}
= \frac{\frac{3600}{4550}}{\frac{100}{250}}
\approx 1.98
$$

Comment: This is what I was trying to get at but couldn’t articulate. In essence was looking for the risk ratio.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since the amount of insured people **with** the disease is $3600$ and the amount of uninsured people **with** the disease is $950$, the ratio is indeed
$$
3600:950.
$$

Comment: Thank you for responding. If I were to use the other calculation, I.e. ratio of (3600/3700):(950/1100), what would that tell me? I guess I know the two approaches are different, but I don’t understand why.

Comment: The second calculation corresponds to "the ratio of insured people to uninsured people", regardless of having the disease or not.

Comment: I realized that what I was looking for was the risk ratio and not simply the ratio. I know how to calculate it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user25025 No problem. Don't forget to upvote the response if it was helpful :)